# Jira - REST API - Importing Assets - Objects Identical value varies each execution - Why? How to Fix?

Tags: python-3.x, rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I hope you're fine,

You'll see, I'm trying to perform an ASSETs import automation, following the next guide:

[Imports REST API Guide](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/assets/imports-rest-api-guide/workflow/)

I have successfully performed the automation, reading a CSV and submitting the data, Update and Create work both without any issue

The thing is, I need to make a report if the automation went well (or at least if it seems to)

When the importing is done, I get the following response performing an API REST call to the ***getExecutionStatus*** url (see the **Step 5b: Start an import** in the Imports REST API Guide):

**NOTE:** This time I'm performing an import without any new ASSET nor ASSET update (since I'll be doing the import daily and a non-change case could present)

```
{
    "status": "DONE",
    "progressResult": {
        "type": "IMPORT",
        "id": 100,
        "started": "2023-04-13T09:59:57.941+00:00",
        "ended": "2023-04-13T10:00:01.666+00:00",
        "objectSchemaId": 1,
        "result": "OK",
        "status": "FINISHED",
        "infoMessage": "No data to import",
        "jobId": "19747985-e0a4-4g83-af0c-f757c4fceb34",
        "importSourceId": "89e6a7ad-2cda-4c0f-80e3-71d9ae35caf8",
        "populatedObjectTypes": [
            "Book"
        ],
        "onlyExecutedForObjectTypes": [],
        "objectTypeResultMap": {
            "1": {
                "id": null,
                "objectTypeName": "Book",
                "objectTypeId": 1,
                "objectsUpdated": 0,
                "objectsCreated": 0,
                "objectsIdentical": 175,
                "objectsMissingUpdated": 0,
                "objectsMissingDeleted": 0,
                "entriesInSource": 260,
                "duplicateEntries": 0,
                "emptyLabelEntries": 0,
                "emptyExternalIdEntries": 0,
                "objectsFilteredWithQlQuery": 0,
                "errorMessages": null,
                "readExternalDataTimeInMs": 6,
                "mapExternalDataTimeInMs": 0,
                "qlQueryFilteringTimeInMs": 0,
                "decidingActionsTimeInMs": 10,
                "writeInsightDataTimeInMs": 0,
                "postFunctionTimeInMs": 0,
                "executionTimeInMs": 16,
                "objectsWithUpdatedReferences": 0
            }
        },
        "errorMessages": null,
        "totalNumberEntriesInImport": 260
    }
}
```

I was thinking to make a comparision

```
# Using Python 3.x
if objectsUpdated + objectsCreated + objectsIdentical + objectsMissingUpdated + objectsMissingDeleted + duplicateEntries + emptyLabelEntries == entriesInSource:
    return True # All good
else:
    return False # Oh, something happened
```

But **objectsIdentical** varies each execution... with the same CSV... (and I'm performing the tests in a sandbox environment, so, I know nobody is creating / updating ASSETs besides me)

I know that **errorMessages** is an useful field too, but I'm trying to understand this issue

Do you know why is this happening? Or how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Best regards,